# How to implement a user authentication by phone number in telegram bot?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am creating a telegram chat bot written in java in spring boot and need to verify users by their phone numbers. After entering /start command in bot, I want my users automatically to be verified and to send them a message such as "Welcome, dear Customer".

I stored their numbers in my db, but since it is my first experience in bot applications, I do not have any clue about how to achieve it.

Answer (score 2):

Here is  a list to get you started assuming you already have your users phone number in your database as you mentioned above.

1. Pick a third party vendor to send SMS. There are many available with good pricing features. Few are Twilio, Plivo, Nexmo, Amazon SNS etc. Some may want you to rent a numbers to send SMS which can be pretty cheap (long  codes) or expensive (short codes) depending on your volume and the destination country you select.
2. All of these vendors offer client libraries which you can add to your project via Maven or Gradle and call the method to that sends an SMS message. It will be as simple as -

   ```
   smsClient(yourSenderNumber, YourCustomersNumber, "message you want to send");
   ```
3. You can also expose an endpoint (call back URL) that these vendors will make a POST or GET request to if your user (customer) replies to your vendor phone number (yourSenderNumber from above) from their device.

You have plenty to learn and explore but this shall get you going.

Good luck.

Comment: I want to create an API to find users by their phone numbers and verify them in bot by checking whether they exist or not in my database. If they exist, I want my bot sends them a message like "Hello, now you can do certain things by clicking menu items". Hope you got what I mean.